# Caret insert in Angular4+

Tags: angular

I am totally stuck with angular project in doing caret insert to text area at a particular cursor position. I try to insert labels/text dynamically to text area in selected cursor positions.

Can you please help me?

Thanks,
Sreepriya J

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz

Comment: https://codepen.io/andrewarchi/pen/RNNaMa                                                       I want this to be done with Angular4+

Comment: a also tried it is not persisting last selection did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to focus the cursor at specific position you need to use selectionStart native Element

```
var startPos=this.r.nativeElement.selectionStart;
this.r.nativeElement.focus();
```

Then you need to concat the previous value with current value

```
this.r.nativeElement.value=this.r.nativeElement.value.substr(0,this.r.nativeElement.selectionStart)+e+this.r.nativeElement.value.substr(this.r.nativeElement.selectionStart,this.r.nativeElement.value.length);
```

Check the Example Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hn8unq

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach, Try out **insert-text-at-cursor** [npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/insert-text-at-cursor)
First, Install and Import

```
npm install --save insert-text-at-cursor

import insertTextAtCursor from 'insert-text-at-cursor';
```

Usage

```
// Find an element you want on the page
const el = document.getElementById('my-textarea');
insertTextAtCursor(el, 'foobar');
```