# Angular: Getting value from textarea from button directive?

Tags: javascript, angular

So, I'm trying to interact with the value in my textarea in my `mainComponent`

main.component.ts

```
<form 
  [formGroup]="form"
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
    <textarea
      formControlName="formControlTextarea">
    </textarea>
</form>
<app-button></app-button>
```

main.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ... ],
  declarations: [ ButtonDirective ]
})
```

button.component.html

```
<button 
  (click)="handleClick()">{{ label }}</button>
```

button.component.ts

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core"
...
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Output() clickEvent = new EventEmitter();

  handleClick() {
    this.clickEvent.emit(this.label); // not really pertinent
  }
}
```

button.directive.ts

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
...
export class ButtonDirective {
  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) onclick(btn) {
    // how do I get value from textarea, as I ultimately 
    // want this button to insert more text when clicked, 
    // among other things like check cursor position
  }
}
```

Not sure if I am doing this right. What else is needed to interact from a component directive to another component?

Comment: what do you want to achive

Comment: @Chellappan Essentially, I am working on a calculator and I want the number buttons to add their corresponding number to the textarea input depending on where the cursor is... but I'm not exactly sure how to do this from the button Directive

Comment: check this if you are looking for caret https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51257183/caret-insert-in-angular4/51259430#51259430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you question:

[solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/calculator-plugin-a5tp4f)

app.component.html:

```
<div class="container">

    <mat-card>

        <mat-card-header>
            Angular Material Basic Keyboard
        </mat-card-header>

        <textarea readonly class="col" matInput [value]="numberArray.join('')">

      </textarea>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <button (click)="addNumber('1')" buttonDirective mat-button>1</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button (click)="addNumber('2')" buttonDirective mat-button>2</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button (click)="addNumber('3')" buttonDirective mat-button>3</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <button (click)="addNumber('4')" mat-button>4</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button (click)="addNumber('5')" mat-button>5</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button (click)="addNumber('6')" mat-button>6</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <button (click)="addNumber('7')" mat-button>7</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button (click)="addNumber('8')" mat-button>8</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button (click)="addNumber('9')" mat-button>9</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <button (click)="addNumber('*')" mat-button>
            *
          </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button (click)="addNumber('0')" mat-button>
            0
          </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button (click)="numberArray.pop()" mat-button>
            <
          </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </mat-card>

</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
numberArray: Array<string> = [];
  addNumber(number){
    this.numberArray.push(number.toString());
  }
```

Comment: Actually, let's say I have a button labelled "b", when I click it, I want to add a "b" to the textarea where ever the cursor is, if there is no cursor, then just directly to the textarea

Comment: look at edited solution and reply whether it is helpful or not?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/calculator-plugin-a5tp4f visit this link